# Grails, null-value in the legacy DB gives PropertyAccessException

Tags: grails, grails-orm, hibernate-mapping

Even though the field is set as nullable I get the exception when the form is reading it.

Ok, I finally solved it by changing the primitives int to Integer allover. See that in the following answer.

The error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: 
Null value was assigned to a property of primitive type setter of
 com.mytrading.legacy.RoleType.copyToXOR
```

The domain:

```
class RoleType {
    int copyToXOR


static constraints = {
    copyToXOR           nullable:true

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by replacing int with Integer and that seems to work with the legacy database it's at least readable and that's what I need.

```
class RoleType {
    Integer copyToXOR


static constraints = {
    copyToXOR           nullable:true
```